# Basic template question: `const const int*` decay in `const int`

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

The following code

```
template <typename T>
struct A 
{ static void f() {std::cout << "A<T>\n";} };

template <typename T>
struct A<const T>
{ static void f() {std::cout << "A<const T>\n";} };

template <typename T>
struct A<const T*>
{ static void f() {std::cout << "A<const T*>\n";} };



template <typename T>
void f()
{
    A<const T>::f();
}

int main()
{
    f<const int*>();
}
```

doesn't work as I was expecting.

I (wrongly) supposed that the call of `f<const int*>()` call the function `A<const T>::f()` that in this case is `A<const const int*>:f()` and that the `const const int*` collapses into `const int*`. But thats not what the program does because it prints `A<const T>` meaning that `const const int*` (in reallity `const (const int*)`) collapses into `const int`.

But why `const const int*` collapses into `const int`?

Comment: `const T` is `int const* const` (or `const int* const`).

Comment: Nitpicking: term "decay" is for array decaying to pointer to first value in that array.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bdqhq35ac

Comment: No, it's not because "const const int* collapses into const int*". Where do you see `const const int *` here? The third template is more specialized, so it's selected, with `T` deduced to `int`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's a really poor duplicate. OP's question is not about which template is more specialized. Also, the *second* template is more specialized, not the third: it prints `"A<const T>"`.

Comment: @Netfeal that's my question: why is the second template more specialized? Thanks for clarifying my ideas.

Comment: When you wrote `const T` then replacing `T` with `const int *` actually gives: `const (const int *)`, so `const int * const`.

Comment: @MarekR and `const (const int *)` is `const T` and not `const T*` (which is what I was expecting to be, because I was interpreting `const (const int*)` as `const const int*`== `const int*`)

Comment: @Antonio https://godbolt.org/z/6Ko77a7oe

Answer (score 5):

You assumption is wrong. `const const int*` does not "collapse" into `const int`.

When you call `f<const int*>()`, you instantiate `f` with `T = const int* = int const*`. Here, the `int` is `const`, so `T = U*` where `U = const int = int const`.

In `f`, you call `A<const T>::f()`, so you instantiate `A` with a type `T2 = const T = U* const`. Here, the pointer is `const`. The complete type is `const int * const` or `int const * const`. There was never a `const const int*`.

As a result, the `const T` specialization is selected, where `T = int const*`. The `const T*` version is less specialized because that's a pointer to `const T`, not a `const` pointer. Adding yet another specialization makes it more clear:

```
template <typename T>
struct A<const T* const>
{ static void f() {std::cout << "A<const T* const>\n";} };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9r7KME4xh)

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to understand this situation if you reverse your `const` placement.  That is, for any type `T`, `const T` is equivalent to `T const`.  In fact, that's the "normal" way to use `const`.  Normally `const` applies to the type directly to its left.  The special case is that if `const` is the first word in a type it applies to the type directly to its right, but that special case can make templates a bit confusing.

So `f<const int*>()` is equivalent to `f<int const*>()`.  Note that it's the `int` that's `const`, not the pointer: `int const*` means "non-constant pointer to a constant `int`".

In `f<int const*>()`, since `const T` is equivalent to `T const` and `T` is `int const*`, `T const` becomes `int const* const`: "constant pointer to a constant `int`".

There is no type `T` for which `T const*` can match `int const* const`, so that partial specialization of `A` is not viable.